# Plane of intersection of two spheres

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, 3d, spheres

What is the plane of intersection of spheres $$x^2+y^2+z^2+2x+2y+2z+2=0$$ and $$x^2+y^2+z^2+x+y+z-\frac{1}{4}=0$$

I am not sure of how to do this, i just subtracted the two equations and i got a plane equation $$4x+4y+4z=-9$$ But i think its not correct since when two spheres meet we get a curved surface or solid. please correct me

Comment: the answer is correct.

Comment: The intersection is a circle, and it lies in some plane, but I would not refer to this plane as the "plane of intersection" of the two spheres. I think it's a somewhat strange term.

Answer (score 5):

Looks fine.

[image: two spheres and intersection plane, intersection curve]

The red sphere is the one of your first equation, the green one the one of your second equation.

The yellow circle is the intersection of both sphere surfaces.

The light blue plane is the intersection plane you calculated.

Comment: thanks can i know which software you used for 3D

Comment: I used [GeoGebra](http://www.geogebra.org/) version 5. On Windows 7 and iOS 9 I have 3D support. The above image was created simply entering the equations for the spheres and plane. The intersection curve was calculated using the surface intersection tool.

Answer (score 3):

Let $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ be a point that belong to both spheres, then it satisfies both equations and any linear combination of them, in particular the linear combination
\begin{align}
x_1^2+y_1^2+z_1^2+2x_1+2y_1+2z_1+2-\left(\color{blue}{x_1^2+y_1^2+z_1^2+x_1+y_1+z_1-\frac{1}{4}}\right)&=0\\
x_1+y_1+z_1+\frac{9}{4}&=0
\end{align}
So the point belong to the plane $4x+4y+4z+9=0$.

Answer (score 3):

Every sphere in 3-space can be described by the equation,

$$ (\vec{x}-\vec{x}_0)^2 - R^2 = 0,  $$

In our case we have two spheres with different centers, call these $\vec{q}$ and $\vec{p}$. Let $r$ be the radius of the sphere with center $\vec{q}$ and $R$ be the radius of the sphere with center $\vec{p}$.

The intersection of the two spheres satisfies the equation of each sphere. We will we subtract the two equations to obtain a new equation which must be satisfied by the intersection,

$$ (\vec{x}-\vec{q})^2 - (\vec{x}-\vec{p})^2 + R^2- r^2 = 0,  $$

simplifying this we get,

$$ 2 \vec{x} \cdot ( \vec{p}-\vec{q} ) + \vec{q}^2 + \vec{p}^2 + R^2 - r^2 =0,$$

which is a plane with normal vector, $\vec{p}-\vec{q}$. The points on the intersection then must satisfy this equation, i.e., lie on this plane; and satisfy the equation for each of the spheres.

This method works because the validity of the equation for the plane stems from the fact that the equation of each sphere is satisfied by $\vec{x}$. If $\vec{x}$ is not an element of either sphere, then we can't claim that the difference of the two equations is still $0$. In this sense the new equation is only valid if the original two are, which is exactly what we need.

Comment: Can you show how to obtain the equation for the circle defined by the intersection of the spheres?

Comment: @StanShunpike, the calculation would be pretty involved, and I don't presently have the time to work it all out. I can provide list of steps I would follow.

Comment: @StanShunpike

For a parametric equation of the circle of intersection I might do the following very general approach for calculating space curves of intersection. (1) Determine a point which is common to the plane of intersection and one of the spheres. (2) Calculate the normal vector to the plane and calculate a formula for the field of normals to the sphere (these don't have to be normalized). (3) Define a tangent vector field by the cross product of the two normals. The integral curve of this field that passes through the point determined in step (1) is the circle.

Comment: @StanShunpike If we are comfortable assuming the intersection is a circle then we could simplify those steps:
 
(1) Use coordinates with the sphere of radius $R$ centered at the origin and the sphere of radius $r$ centered at a point on the +Z axis a distance $\| \vec{p}-\vec{q}\|$ above the origin. (2) Form a triangle in the ZX plane with points at the center of each sphere and a point of intersection between the spheres. The side lengths of this triangle are $r$, $R$, and $\| \vec{p}-\vec{q}\|$.

Comment: @StanShunpike

(3) Determine the distance from origin to plane of intersection and the radius of the circle of intersection. (4) Form the parametric equation of the circle in these coordinates. Map back to the original coordinates by an appropriate affine transformation.

Comment: @StanShunpike, 

Hope that is helpful, sorry I don't have time to work out all the details. If you end up posting a question let me know and I can try to post an answer when I have more time.

Answer (score 2):

Rewriting into standard forms,

$S_{1}$: $\: (x+1)^{2}+(y+1)^{2}+(z+1)^{2}=1$

$S_{2}$: $\: (x+\frac{1}{2})^{2}+(y+\frac{1}{2})^{2}+(z+\frac{1}{2})^{2}=1$

Both have radii of $1$ and distance between their centres $d=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$.

Therefore, $r_{1}=r_{2}<d<r_{1}+r_{2}$ implying they intersect.

In general, any two non-concentric spheres $(S=0,S'=0)$ have one **radical plane** $(S-S'=0)$ no matter there's an intersection or not. We can generate a family of spheres with same radical plane in the form of $S+kS'=0$.